# Is the entire working copy "at one branch"?

Tags: git, branch

This is a very basic question but maybe I just don't know how to phrase my query well enough to find an answer.

Let me begin with a SVN example. SVN doesn't have a "current branch" as a property of a working copy, so I'll give the example with revisions instead. Consider a working copy with the dirs `foo` and `bar` in it. In SVN one can `update` foo to an earlier version, but keep `bar` at `HEAD`.

Is it possible in an analogical git working copy to checkout one branch in dir `foo` without changing the branch checked out in `bar`?

If not, why not?

Comment: There are several good answers for getting to where you'd *like* to be, but the short answer is: (1) yes, the entire work-tree is considered to be on a single branch; (2) yes, you can extract individual files or entire subtrees from another branch, but when you do, you must consider what happens to Git's "index", aka "staging area". Most other VCSes either have nothing like the index at all, or else hide it; Git forces you to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is [possible](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows) to have multiple working copies since Git 2.5. The command is [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). As an example, in order to checkout existing branch `foo` into directory `foo-working-copy` you could do this:

```
git worktree add ../foo-working-copy foo
cd ../foo-working-copy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `checkout` individual files, or groups of files, to any version you want.

However, this leaves the HEAD & index untouched, so these files show up as being modified (like local changes you haven't `add`ed or `commit`ted yet). There's no way to tell git that some (groups of) files *should* be different versions than others.

If you need to control versioning of different sub-directories independently, make them separate submodule repos.

Using worktrees just means you have multiple working copies of your repo, potentially displaying different branches, but sharing back-end storage. Each one is still a full copy of the working tree at the checked-out commit.

Comment: This is mostly right but has one important glitch: if you `git checkout <commit> -- <path>` an individual file or tree, that leaves `HEAD` untouched (as you say) but *updates the index* (so that the staged-for-next-commit version is now the one you just checked out). Somewhat obnoxiously, when checking out files with `--ours` or `--theirs` during a conflicted merge, this does NOT update the index. It took me a long time to learn this as it seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

In git, a revision is a commit. A commit is a snapshot of the whole repo. This snapshot records what the tree structure is like and what contents each file holds at the moment when `git commit` is done. If `foo` and `bar` belong to the same repo, they are tied to a same revision. When a revision is checked out, `foo` is updated to what it is like in this revision's snapshot and so is `bar`. This is how git-checkout works in most cases.

Git-checkout can also update part of its files or sub-directories. So it's possible to checkout `foo` of revision A and `bar` of revision B if foo and bar are not nested. The side-effect is that the working tree becomes dirty. A dirty working tree means you may lose the uncommitted changes, which are not tracked by git yet. But if you know exactly what you are doing and know well of the possible loss, this side-effect could just be ignored. We could also initialize `foo` and `bar` as two separate git repos. Now checking out `foo` and `bar` with their own revision is a full checkout in each repo, so that neither of the repos gets dirty. But we have to maintain two repos now.

If `foo` is a sub-directory of `bar`, we could initialize `bar` as the repo which takes over `foo`. When `bar` is checked out, `foo` is updated too because it's now part of `bar`. But you can still partially checkout `foo` and keep the other files as they are, or checkout others with some revision and keep `foo` unchanged. Another option is to make two repos, with `foo` as a submodule of `bar`. This is a bit complex to maintain. It's also okay not to deal with a repo and its sub-repo. Take them as two independent repos, but you'll have to git-ignore `foo` in `bar` and always remember to copy/clone `foo` to the right place inside `bar`, which could have been done by git-submodule.

I recommend you to read the chapter, Git Internals, of Pro Git. It helps to understand how git  works internally and I can promise you will be able to draw the commit graph with all the refs including branches, tags, HEAD and so on in your mind and be a master of manipulating commit history.